# Difference between typing and pasteing in a field

Tags: javascript, security, search, xss

If I use xss, what's the difference between typing in ALERT('DSSA');, or just paste it to a search textfield? In a site, typing works, and makes the alert, but if I just paste it, than it doesn't. To prevent the question, I don't want to hack any site, I'm just interested in network security.

thanks for the answer

Comment: pasting can be detected by `onblur` event I guess.

Comment: Are you trying to say, typing `alert('dssa');` on the site, pops up an alert box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be because the programmer who built the website is lazy and hasn't listened for the `onpaste` event.

Typing fires the `onkeydown`, `onkeypress` and `onkeyup` events, and are the *standard* events to consider when watching for user input.

It would seem those are the only events the programmer has listened for (which makes this irrelevant of network security).

---

If this is not the case, then he'll be using two different event handlers for the events; one which escapes the input, and in the other he's forgotten.

Comment: paste is what doesnt work, so you mean, the site is defended against pasting the code, but not against directly typing in the code, wow, thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I may not have understood the question properly.

Typing triggers `keyUp`, `keyDown` and `keyPress` events on the element. If the codes are programmed to capture them only, then only *those events will be captured*.

Pasting can be done using keyboards, mouse and browser options. So this depends on **which events you are listening too**. There is a separate event called **`onpaste`** which will ease everything.

> What I mean is, lets say my code is written to capture the pasting my pressing "Ctrl" + "v" only, but if mouse and browser options are used to paste on the
>   element, then it is configured to capture mouse events also, it cannot
>   be captured.